# Eclipse Plugin: How to modify the extension "org.eclipse.ui.newWizards"?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, wizard

I have a wizard that should be launched in different ways: from the menu (*org.eclipse.ui.menus + org.eclipse.ui.actionSets*) and from the New context menu. For the later I used the extension *org.eclipse.ui.newWizards* to add the wizard into the context menu. So far, so good...

For some reasons I had to subclass the wizard dialog (changed the finish button text in the dialog). If the wizard is launched from the menu, the action (defined in *org.eclipse.ui.actionSets*) creates and opens this special wizard dialog and everything is fine.

If the wizard is launched from the context menu (*org.eclipse.ui.newWizards*), the internal class *NewWizardShortcutAction* is taken that creates the "normal" wizard dialog (and not my subclass) to open the wizard.

Is there any way to modify the implementation of the extension point that only my subclassed wizard dialog is used?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also trying to do the same. The way I will be doing this is to register my own custom action, by removing the old action, will post back the solution if it works !

Update: I ended up using a different approach. If you see the run method in NewWizardShortcutAction, it is just calling init, creating the WizardDialog and opening it. So in my override of the init in MyWizard class, I just used my own MyWizardDialog extending from WizardDialog and opened it. Subsequently, I need to make that the run function will not re-open the WizardDialog, so I track that using a boolean in MyWizard that will disallow getting any pages so that the WizardDialog in the run method will not be displayed.

This is a hacky solution but works !

Answer (score 0):

By default the command uses `org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler.New` to launch the new wizard dialog, and that's the default handler provided to the command.

It would be possible to register a different handler at the Workbench Window level, and that would override the default handler while a Workbench Window was active.  It could be done in the plugin.xml or in your application ActionBarAdvisor:

```
IHandlerService hs = (IHandlerService) window.getService(IHandlerService.class);
hs.activateHandler(IWorkbenchCommandConstants.FILE_NEW, new MyNewHandler());
```

But you would have to implement whatever support was needed in the handler to launch the wizard with the correct selection.